# I am getting BUILD FAILED ,When i try to deploy Android Application in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: android

I have just started with android in Eclipse and now i want to do the same in netbeans 6.8, i Configured netbeans with all the (andoird's)jar files..etc..whatever it asked me to do.,now it is possible to open the android project in the my netbeans 6.8, but the problem that i get now,

While i try to start new Android Project,Its getting opened and in the console ,its saying that build is successful,after i code the simple helloworld app and once i clean and build the app,its showing me as Build failed..Please help me to rectify the same..

I am very much annoyed becos of this problem for the last 2 days..

This is the error that i got...

```
 Created dir: C:\Android Practices\workspace\AndroidApplication2\dist
=C:\Android was unexpected at this time.
 C:\Android Practices\workspace\AndroidApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:411: exec    returned: 255
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Please help me out in finding this problem.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem and it seems to come from the whitespaces existing in the path. Try changing the directory name to one without white spaces or change the path in the ant to something like this:

```
<project ... >

<property file="local.properties" />

<property name="sdk.dir" value="C:\Docume~1\user\android-sdk-windows" />

...
```

which is what solved my problem. Notice that Docume~1 is exactly 8 character long, I remember that was important.

I hope that helps.

Edit: I updated the answer to mark where to add the line, but unless your local.properties file contains something else apart from the definition of the sdk.dir, you can delete that line

Comment: Hi,Maragues, Thanks for very valuable response
but, in which file i have to change the path of the ant...like

<property name="sdk.dir" value="C:\Docume~1\user\android-sdk-windows" />